# When/where (if at all) is radiation emitted in Stern-Gerlach sequential experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Assuming an experimental setup like experiment 2 on this Wikipedia page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment#Experiment_2

100% of fermions entering the second apparatus are spin up and 50% of them exit the second apparatus with spin down. When/where/if at all is a photon emitted when a fermion passes through the second apparatus?

I'll try to guess the answer - for a fermion that enters with spin up (z) and exits with spin up (x) no photon is emitted. For a fermion that eventually exits with spin down (x) a photon will be emitted from the region near the entry area of the second apparatus.

On the other hand I have a sneaking feeling that no photon will be emitted at all because we aren't seeing a change in z-axis spin up/down but a change of axis followed by a random selection of up/down in the x-axis.

If I had the resources to do the experiments that would be great but failing that perhaps a physicist could tell me the outcome of the experiment from your knowledge of experimental results or from first principals. I'd be grateful.

Comment: What photon are you talking about?

Comment: Perhaps I've got totally the wrong idea here since I'm not a physicist and it was a very long time ago that I had a superficial education in quantum mechanics as a Biochemistry UG. But, isn't there a drop in potential energy if say an electron transitions from spin up to spin down in a magnetic field? So, I would assume that a photon is emitted with a corresponding wavelength. Am I wrong?

Comment: but it's not changing state

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: @JEB Forgot to reference your name. Can you expand on that comment?

Comment: @JEB Thanks for the answer - I edited my question title to acknowledge the 'what photons' comment.

Answer (score 2):

When an atom changes its spin state, it also changes its magnetic moment. This may happen via lengthy Larmor precession of the magnetic moment or just direct shortest alignment, but in any case, during this process it should emit EM radiation.

Let us estimate frequency of the emitted radiation based on quantum transition between two spin states in magnetic field $B$. Difference of energy between two orthogonal spin states can be estimated as

$$
\Delta E = 2\mu B
$$

where $\mu$ is magnetic moment which we can estimate as $\frac{e\hbar}{2m_e}$, and $B$ is magnetic field (in Teslas). So

$$
\Delta E \approx \frac{e\hbar B}{m_e}.
$$

Using the relation $\Delta E = 2\pi\hbar f$, we get for frequency of the emitted radiation

$$
f \approx \frac{eB}{m_e}.
$$

For $B=2 $T (quite a strong field), we get $f = 350 $GHz, thus we expect at most microwave radiation frequencies, or lower (radio frequencies, like in NMR). The emitted radiation due to a thin stream of atoms is very weak, but if we could detect it somehow and measure peak of its frequency spectrum, we could use the above formula to find out $B$ which was acting on the atom at the time of emission, and this would point to probable regions in between the magnets where the emission happened. I don't know if such an experiment was ever done. The radiation is probably very weak and hard to measure.

Comment: Most discussions of the Stern-Gerlach experiments make no mention of the emission of radiation and I can see that may because of the difficulty in measurement.  I was thinking that possibly the state change occurs when the particle is just starting to 'feel' the magnetic field and so the frequency would be very low and hard to detect.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, and low frequencies may be hard to measure due to the fact that intensity of emission is often proportional to some power of frequency (for classic oscillator, intensity of emission is proportional to $f^4$), so indeed low frequencies have weaker radiation that may be harder to measure. However, the weaker the magnetic field, the more slowly should it change the spin, so most of the spins should be flipping in regions where the field intensity has some treshold value, larger than zero.

Comment: Your answer and comments here are really helpful to my understanding. But I'm intrigued by JEB's statement that there is no change of state which seems directly contradictory to your comments.  I'm holding off accepting your answer in the hope of some clarification. BTW, JEB's 'what photons?' question led me to read your answer to "what is a real photon?" and I think I'll avoid the word photon from now on as I don't feel qualified to use it in any of its multiple correct senses!

Comment: I don't see what he means - both velocity and spin state is influenced by the SG magnets. That's why the beam splits there - first, the atom gets new spin state which is one of two options defined by direction of magnetic field, and then based on this spin state(and the corresponding magnetic moment) magnetic field causes change in velocity of the atom so the beam splits into two beams. Magnetic moments in external magnetic field are known to radiate, that's how NMR works.

Comment: I'm swinging over to @JEB point of view. Doesn't NMR and ESR work by applying externally generated radio frequency radiation? And this is input into a system where the particles are already bathed in a magnetic field? If radiation comes out due to a change from + to - states in the chosen axis it is **not** due to a change in the direction of the magnetic field but a spontaneous event.

Comment: Yes NMR works by applying oscillating magnetic field pulses to medium that is in strong magnetic field, and then recording the EM response of the medium via some coils, as total EM field is influenced by emission from the nuclei in the medium.

Comment: > *"If radiation comes out due to a change from + to - states in the chosen axis it is not due to a change in the direction of the magnetic field but a spontaneous event."* I'm not sure what you mean. Radiation comes out whenever magnetic moment (and thus spin state) changes, and that happens only due to spin state entering external magnetic field where it is not an eigenstate (e.g. x state entering z magnet).

Comment: It seems to me that the eigenstates are defined by the axis of the magnetic field and in the NMR/ESR situation the axis stays the same so there are real changes of state. In the SG experiment there is a change in the axis of the magnetic field so there isn't a change of state but a change in the definition of state such that a pure state in the 1st axis has to be reframed as a mixed state in the 2nd axis.

Comment: I'm accepting that if you put pulses of radiation into the S.G. experiment you could convert some 'right' particles into 'left' particles as they pass through the magnetic field and that would turn the right blob on the detector into a smear that runs towards the left. Also, if the particles took long enough to pass through the apparatus some of those in the 'left' state might drop down into the 'right' state and emit some radiation. That would create a smear on the left of the detector.

Comment: > *"but a change in the definition of state such that a pure state in the 1st axis has to be reframed as a mixed state in the 2nd axis."* I don't think that's right. Reframing how state is expressed does not change it, and thus also does not change its purity, $|z+\rangle$ is pure and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|x+\rangle + |x-\rangle)$ is pure as well, it's the same pure state. Mixed state would mean we have a mix of pure states, e.g. 50% of atoms in  $|z+\rangle$ and 50% in $|z-\rangle$, and then we would use density matrix, not just kets.

Comment: O.K. I'm sticking my neck out here but I don't think that's what 'mixed state' in the context of QM means. A *single* QM particle can be in a mixed state until a pulse is observed on a detector when the wave function collapses and you have a pure state.

Comment: I agree, single atom spin can be described by mixed state. But after we block the z- beam, atoms in the z+ beam are in pure state $|z+\rangle$, not in a mixed state.

Comment: The point is that if you boil it down to the two complex numbers in the spinor that defines the state, the pure state $|z+\rangle$ is *identical to* an infinite variety of mixed states.

Comment: In what sense? Density matrix of $|z+\rangle$ is projector obeying the relation $\rho^2=\rho$, a mixed state does not obey it.

Comment: I realise I've strayed over the borderline between what I understand and what I don't understand. I'll have to do some study before I can answer that question. Thanks for the challenge - it's keeping me on my toes.

Comment: Many thanks for all your input into this.  I've done further searching and found sources that predict radiation and other sources that predict no radiation. I think I need to ask another reformulated question specifically about the existence of experimental data.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

So in the 2nd row, the beam entering the 2nd SG device is in a pure spin state:

$$ |\uparrow\rangle = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(|\rightarrow\rangle +
|\leftarrow) $$

where the up/down (right/left) kets are spin $m_s=\pm\frac 1 2$ eigenstates along the $z$ ($x$) axis.

The SG device then entangles spin and spatial position so the exiting 2 beams at $x = x_{\pm}$ are:

$$ \psi = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}(\delta(x_+)|\rightarrow\rangle + \delta(x_-)|\leftarrow\rangle)$$

No spins were flipped. The magnetic field gradient $(dB/dx)$ separated the spins into two spots at $x_{\pm}$, and that's how they are detected, not by the emission of photons.

That $\psi$ cannot be written as a single product of $\psi(x)$ and a spin state shows the entanglement.

Comment: Those are different spin states, the initial one is along the z-axis, the final one is along the x-axis, so the change caused by the second magnet is 90 degrees, not 180 degrees. So strictly speaking it is not a "flip" (180 degrees), but still change of spin and thus also magnetic moment does happen. This should produce *some* (weak) radiation, just as in NMR.

Comment: @JEB I think (not totally confident) that this answer is a rigorous expression of my second intuitive guess at the answer. If I look at the point before the beam reaches the 2nd SG device, the beam is in a pure state with reference to the z axis but this pure state is identical to a mixed state comprised of a mixture of the two possible pure states defined by the x axis. Is that a fair summary of the key point?

Comment: Hope I'm still getting this right... In experiment 3 if we compute the mixed state wave function at the surface of the detector labelled 'x-' we can find a probability of detection. If a particle FAILS to be detected there the mixed wave function collapses to just one of its pure components, $|\rightarrow\rangle$ and on it goes to the third S-G device. There the now pure $|\rightarrow\rangle$ state is identical to a mixed state $\frac1{\sqrt 2}(|\uparrow\rangle +
|\downarrow\rangle)$.

Comment: @Jon_m You are getting it right. The quantum magic occurs when you remove the beam-stop at $x_-$ and the two beam recombine coherently into pure $|\uparrow\rangle$, but if you measured which beam the particle was in, a la detection at the slit in Young's 2-slit experiment, they become incoherent and then you get 2 incoherent beams, each a combination of $\uparrow + \downarrow$. To write that state down, you need a density matrix.

Comment: A lot of pennies have dropped reading your explanations so thanks. (BTW I had to go and find a question to answer in order to earn the privilege to mark yours and Jan's answers as both useful!)